# How tetrieve in python

Tags: odoo

when I enter a value as a date in my interface how to retrieve it in python

```
class Attachement(models.Model):
date_atta   =   fields.Date(string='Date Attachement')
```

Comment: def attachement_progressbar(self,vals):
   print get(vals['date_atta'])
   date_at = context.get('date_atta',False)
   print date_at

Answer (score 0):

for example if you need to retreive it from a method in the same class:

```
def your_method(self):
   yourfield = self.date_atta
```

And you can use yourfield as you wish. I hope this help you.

Comment: no I want the value entered in the xml interface Dayana

Comment: @Taha normally you just need to put the field name in the xml. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Dayana I try to retrieve the date to see if it exists in my table